# Upgrading Paraview on Ubuntu to a newer version not yet available in repository

Tags: ubuntu, installation, updates, repository

I have a desktop Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [*] and have installed Paraview **4.0.1** from the Ubuntu Software Centre, which is told to be a safe and well-proven way to engage with installations.

I have seen though that the latest Paraview available from the developers http://www.paraview.org/download/ is already version **5.2**. The lag is substantial, so I would like to upgrade Paraview on my Ubuntu.

I think that the most relevant page I have found is http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install#On_Unix-like_operating_systems: which seems to suggest that you need a fresh install, which could turn out to be undesirably laborious.

Is there a possibility to ask Ubuntu to upgrade the existing Paraview by using the more recent files I am downloading from the developers' website? This would combine the best of the two worlds.

[*] Note I will not consider upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04